# How to convert seconds into UnixtimeStamp in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar =  [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    // find next date where the minutes are zero
    NSDate *nextHour = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:now matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute value:0 options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
    // get the number of seconds between now and next hour
    NSDateComponents *componentsToNextHour = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:now toDate:nextHour options:0];
    //NSLog(@"%ld", componentsToNextHour.second);
    NSString *dec = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)componentsToNextHour.second];
```

In the above code, I convert the current date and time into seconds, but I am unable to convert these seconds into unixtimestamp, any ideas on how to go about this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. If you are asking for the Unix timestamp at which the next hour starts, do this:

```
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar =  [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    // find next date where the minutes are zero
    NSDate *nextHour = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:now matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute value:0 options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
    time_t unixTimestampAtWhichNextHourStarts = (time_t)nextHour.timeIntervalSince1970;
    NSLog(@"ts=%ld", (long)unixTimestampAtWhichNextHourStarts);
```

Comment: Excellent, so i dont need to first convert into seconds, Fantastic, Highly appreciated, you save my lot of time, i was stuck hours into it.